# Java socket can't reply outside of the loop

Tags: java, php, sockets

I have a Java server that listens to connections from a PHP client and replies back. My problem is I can't write anything to outputStream after reading the inputStream.

```
while (true)
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                clientSocket.setSoTimeout(2000);

                if (!clientSocket.getInetAddress().equals(clientSocket.getLocalAddress())) {
                    clientSocket.close();
                    continue;
                }

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

                LinkedList<String> messageFromPHP = new LinkedList<>();

                String message = "";
                while ((message = br.readLine()) != null)
                    messageFromPHP.add(message);

                bw.write("test_message\n");
                bw.flush();

                bw.close();
                br.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                serverSocket.close();
            }
```

^^ This makes both the PHP client and Java Server stuck forever. (I have added SoTimeout to the server to prevent that)

```
while (true)
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                clientSocket.setSoTimeout(2000);

                if (!clientSocket.getInetAddress().equals(clientSocket.getLocalAddress())) {
                    clientSocket.close();
                    continue;
                }

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

                LinkedList<String> messageFromPHP = new LinkedList<>();

                String message = "";
                while ((message = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    messageFromPHP.add(message);
                    bw.write("test_message\n");
                    bw.flush();
                }

                bw.close();
                br.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                serverSocket.close();
            }
```

^^ However this one works perfectly fine and I don't know why. I'm sure these while loops end because I can print messageFromPHP without a problem with both codes.

So, how can I avoid doing everything inside the readLine loop?

Edit: To make things more clear: I want to write and read like the first code. But when I'm reading the input, I can't write to output so I have to use the second code and I don't want to. I'm trying to store the input inside the messageFromPHP list and write to output after that according to the input in the list.

Comment: What are you asking -- how to create a thread?

Comment: Nope. As I stated in my question, I have to write to outputStream after the readLine loop but I can't do that. I can write inside the loop or before the loop but I can't write after I read every line from the client. Or maybe the while loop still running while I'm trying to write to outputStream...

Comment: In other words, you want to create a separate thread so that reading does not block writing, and if not why not? Don't you want reading and writing to go on simultaneously?

Comment: When PHP client try to read the output of the first code, it simply get stuck and since it can't close the socket the Java server is also stuck forever. But with the second code, PHP client can read the reply of the Server and close the socket as it supposed to do.

I want to write after reading is done.